# Starting IIS Express cmd rather than VS2022

Tags: swagger, iis-express, asp.net-core-6.0, applicationhost, iis-express-10

The ASP.Net Core 6 Web Api runs under IIS Express via VS2022 just fine and allows me to load the swagger page (http://localhost:8084/swagger/index.html):

```
#Software: Microsoft Internet Information Services 10.0
#Version: 1.0
#Date: YYYY-DD-MM 17:49:22
#Fields: date time s-ip cs-method cs-uri-stem cs-uri-query s-port cs-username c-ip cs(User-Agent) cs(Referer) sc-status sc-substatus sc-win32-status time-taken
YYYY-DD-MM 17:49:22 ::1 GET /_framework/aspnetcore-browser-refresh.js - 8084 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/107.0.0.0+Safari/537.36 http://localhost:8084/swagger/index.html 200 0 0 6
YYYY-DD-MM 17:49:22 ::1 GET /swagger/index.html - 8084 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/107.0.0.0+Safari/537.36 - 200 0 0 3664
YYYY-DD-MM 17:49:22 ::1 GET /_vs/browserLink - 8084 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/107.0.0.0+Safari/537.36 http://localhost:8084/swagger/index.html 200 0 0 59
YYYY-DD-MM 17:49:22 ::1 GET /swagger/v1/swagger.json - 8084 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/107.0.0.0+Safari/537.36 http://localhost:8084/swagger/index.html 200 0 0 149
```

When running it from the cmdline:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\iisexpress" /config:applicationhost.config /site:TheWebApi
```

Swagger does not load returning a HTTP 500:

```
#Software: Microsoft Internet Information Services 10.0
#Version: 1.0
#Date: 2022-11-19 17:54:41
#Fields: date time s-ip cs-method cs-uri-stem cs-uri-query s-port cs-username c-ip cs(User-Agent) cs(Referer) sc-status sc-substatus sc-win32-status time-taken
2022-11-19 17:54:41 ::1 GET /swagger/index.html - 8084 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/107.0.0.0+Safari/537.36 - 500 0 574 8
2022-11-19 17:54:41 ::1 GET /favicon.ico - 8084 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/107.0.0.0+Safari/537.36 http://localhost:8084/swagger/index.html 500 0 574 0
```

Lex Li's blog [How Visual Studio Launches IIS Express to Debug ASP.NET Core Apps](https://halfblood.pro/how-visual-studio-launches-iis-express-to-debug-asp-net-core-apps-d7fd3677e3c3) was very helpful in me gaining more information on what is going on.  Clearly, VS2022 is doing some magic to make things run in debug mode.  In my case, I am trying to get a desktop app to launch the ASP.Net Core 6 application, so debugging is not a concern.  When I looked into the event log, I found what might be the problem, but don't know the solution:

```
Application 'C:\Users\sam\source\repos\WebApplication1\' failed to start. Exception message:
Executable was not found at 'C:\Users\sam\source\repos\WebApplication1\bin\Debug\net5.0\WebApplication1.exe'
```

The problem is the application is .Net 6, not .Net 5.  It was originally .Net 5, but it has been upgraded to .Net 6.  This has me thinking...

I did just create a new .Net WebApi project (WebApplication2) to compare the applicationhost.conf generated vs the real project (WebApplication1).  The WebApplication1 has the following section which was not in WebApplicaiton2:

```
<site name="WebApplication1" id="2">
<application path="/" applicationPool="WebApplication1 AppPool">
  <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="C:\Users\sam\source\repos\WebApplication1" />
</application>
<bindings>
  <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:8084:localhost" />
</bindings>
</site>
```

Since I don't want Visual Studio 2022 to be taken into account, should physicalPath="C:\Users\sam\source\repos\WebApplication1\bin\Debug\net6.0"?

Comment: Don't assume VS uses just a simple command line call to launch IIS Express. No. It is much more complex than that, https://halfblood.pro/how-visual-studio-launches-iis-express-to-debug-asp-net-core-apps-d7fd3677e3c3

Comment: Lex Li, thank you so much for that blog post, I appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

In my particular case, there is a desktop application that is managing the execution of the ASP.Net Core 6 Web API application in question.  It turns out that it is possible to publish the ASP.Net Core 6 Web API application into a single EXE, which is called a [Self-contained deployment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/deploy-with-vs?tabs=vs156#simpleSelf).  This is what I needed.